# Building a query with two tables using SUM

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables that I need to gather data from, then add up the sum of one field and return it if the sum is over a certain amount.

Affiliates Table  - Table1: `[id]`
Commissions Table - Table1: `[affiliate_id][amount]`

I need to grab only affiates where the total commissions 'amount' is over 30.

I will also need to return all of the data from both tables into a single array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the HAVING clause.

```
SELECT affiliate_id, SUM(amount) total_amount 
FROM commissions GROUP BY affiliate_id 
HAVING total_amount > 30
```